# Connecting two routers wirelessly to extend wifi signal

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge

I'm trying to extent my wifi signal with additional router wirelessly. My 'primary' router is Linksys WRT54gl and the second one is Linksys E900. Both routers have the same SSID.

main router (connected to modem):

[image]

additional router:

[image]

With those settings, I can see only the main router in a network. Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

These off the shelf routers comes with limited capabilities, So your router can't act as repeater

you would have to install DD-WRT on at least one of them and then use that one as a Repeater and you can use other one as main router

**Connecting to first router**
 1. On the dd-wrt router page click status 
 2. Status > wireless: scroll down and click site survey, then click join the desired network, then continue, then save, then apply.

**More info about bridging on dd-wrt**
[dd-wrt bridge instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge)

**you can install dd-wrt on your e900 if you want to make this as a repeater**
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_E900

Comment: You really should wait to submit an answer until you can write it so its complete the first revision.

Comment: I just want to help the guy

Comment: You can help the guy by posting a complete detailed answer on how to create the type of network he is looking for.  Posting a url to the instructions without some explanation isn't that helpful.  Be specific in the details.  Which is the reason I suggested in the future you wait until you can submit complete answers, instead of incomplete answers, which will appear the review queue for quality reasons.

Comment: @SeanClt Is there no other way to use dd-wrt firmware? Is it something wrong with my current settings?

Comment: @peterremec it seems you are following http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=143751 but this article is hard wired bridge not wireless bridge. similarly in your setting i don't see anywhere where you are connecting the second router to first router

Comment: Linksys E900 is a router not a repeater, if you want to make it a repeater you need to install customer firmwares like DD-WRT otherwise you can just switch the routers as i suggested

Comment: @SeanClt just installed dd-wrt on both routers and did the configuration like this http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Image:Standard_bridge_large.jpg 
It doesn't seem to me like wifi signal is extended... Is there any way to check if the network is set like on the link above?

Comment: @peterremec 1. how do you have these placed physically 2. Are these dual band of single band routers ? 3. If you connect to second router using Lam port are you able to browse Internet

Comment: @SeanClt 1. main router (WRT54GL) upstairs, additional one (E900) downstairs 2. both 2.4 GHz (single) 3. No internet access when connecting with cable.

Comment: @peterremec i can't think of reason why but please check on http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index and let's close this thread